# How to change the style of current link

Tags: jquery

I have a lot of links inside a div

```
<a class='linkL' href='../mc/file01.php'>FILE01</a>
<a class='linkL' href='../mc/file02.php'>FILE02</a>
<a class='linkL' href='../mc/file03.php'>FILE03</a>
```

Now, I want to change the style of the current `.linkL`

JS

```
var path = location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0]; // for example - file01.php

$('.linkL').each(function(){
    var a = $(this).attr('href');
    If (path is contained as substring inside a) {
    $(this).addClass('navact');
    }
});
```

So, the first link should have different class.

Any help.

Comment: You can use `x.contains(y)` to check if the string `x` contains the string `y`.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers - No you can't

Comment: Why is the title "*How to change the style of current link*", if then it seems the question is "*How to check if a string contains a substring*"?

Comment: @Oriol, my problem is how to change the style. Maybe there are other ways except checking the substring.

Comment: @adeneo Strangely enough, on this page I can. I suppose a third party JS file loaded on this page included that. I was a bit surprised when it autocompleted, as I thought it required indexOf. A matter of `String.prototype.contains = function(e) { return this.indexOf(e) > -1; }` I guess. But you were right to correct me of course. I might have been thinking of Java when answering ;)

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers - jQuery has a `.contains()` method as well, but that is for checking elements, there's a pseudo selector `:contains()` that would check for strings, but not like this, here `indexOf` would be the best choice. As you've noted, Stack Overflow probably has a custom String.contains() method if it works here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looking for [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
var path = location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0]; // for example - file01.php

$('.linkL').each(function(){
    var a = $(this).attr('href');
    if ( a.indexOf( path ) != -1 ) {
        $(this).addClass('navact');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why I can't here automatically get your name using `@`? I can do this only inside comment above the answers.

Comment: Because you don't have to adress me by name in a comment to my answer, I'm notified automagically of all comments made to an answer I've posted.